# Understanding why sapply in R returns vector of longer length

Tags: r, sapply

I am parsing through individual lines of code in `R` to get a better understanding of a large function. While I know `sapply` apples a function over a vector, I am having trouble understanding what it is doing in a specific instance. Unfortunately, I cannot find a clear explanation on this exact question elsewhere.

If you simulate data with the sample below code, the variable `Y` is a vector with 2000 values and `calc_sizes` is the number of unique values in Y (87 unique values). When `sapply` is applied to `likelihoods` it is done in the context of `likelihoods[calc_sizes]<-sapply(calc_sizes, nb.likelihood)`. This returns a vector of 688 values

What is `sapply` doing here, and how/why does it return a vector of 688 and not 87?

To be clear, the code is functioning properly - there is no technical issue. I would just prefer to *understand* and *learn* as opposed to blindly writing code that eventually worked (and so I don't have to bug this forum so often).

You should be able to copy and paste the code verbatim to get the results mentioned. Thank you for any insight!

```
#################################################################
#Functions that are needed to generate and apply to sample data
#################################################################
bp <- function(gens=20, init.size=1, offspring, ...){  
  Z <- list() #initiate the list
  Z[[1]] <- init.size #set the first position of the list as the number of index cases
  i <- 1 
  while(sum(Z[[i]]) > 0 && i <= gens) { 
    Z[[i+1]] <- offspring(sum(Z[[i]]), ...) 
    i <- i+1 
  } 
  return(Z)
}
nb.likelihood<-function(x){
  lgamma(k*x+(x-1))-(lgamma(k*x)+lgamma(x+1))+(x-1)*log(r0/k)-(k*x+(x-1))*log(1+r0/k)    
}

####################
#Generate sample data
####################
set.seed(123)
Z<-replicate(n=2000,bp(offspring=rnbinom,mu=0.9,size=0.25)) 
Y<-unlist(lapply(Z,function(x) sum(unlist(x))))

#Generate variables in question 
calc_sizes<-unique(c(1,Y))
likelihoods<-c()
#########################
#line of code in question
#########################
likelihoods[calc_sizes]<-sapply(calc_sizes, nb.likelihood)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specifically answer the reason for 688 is that you are assigning values by un-ordered indexes from values of `calc_size` to the empty vector, `likelihoods`. Specifically, `calc_sizes` comprises of 87 integer values. Notice the smallest term is 1 and largest term is 688.

```
calc_sizes

 [1]   1  40   2   3 180   4  19  21  10  49   6  18   5  11  81  23 186 189   8
[20]  41  27  20   7  12  68   9  25  16 131  15  51  26  22  17 648  24  30  32
[39]  28  36  53  96  47  14 548 109  38  31  99 106  34  39 607 100 233  42  66
[58] 129  33 170 102  70  13  46  63  79  97 447 460 688 346 130  44  69 620 113
[77]  92 256 153  78 462 325  61  64  54  76  86
```

However, your intended `sapply` also contains 87:

```
sapply(calc_sizes, nb.likelihood) 

 [1]  -1.098612 -11.788381  -2.602690  -3.413620 -30.541489  -4.001407
 [7]  -8.187640  -8.575276  -6.146104 -13.154588  -4.881330  -7.987619
[13]  -4.475865  -6.410490 -17.680645  -8.948901 -31.297439 -31.674821
[19]  -5.565697 -11.943435  -9.663029  -8.383385  -5.240275  -6.661805
[25] -15.886160  -5.865802  -9.310881  -7.572668 -24.292698  -7.356445
[31] -13.450466  -9.488087  -8.763676  -7.782825 -87.586858  -9.131222
[37] -10.175841 -10.509013  -9.835872 -11.158148 -13.744013 -19.702968
[43] -12.856183  -7.133302 -75.557026 -21.425116 -11.475373 -10.343221
[49] -20.102594 -21.029806 -10.836219 -11.632377 -82.659672 -20.235490
[55] -37.171587 -12.097586 -15.605646 -24.034010 -10.673316 -29.277798
[61] -20.500835 -16.165367  -6.902190 -12.705964 -15.182243 -17.407459
[67] -19.836336 -63.355209 -64.929415 -92.388061 -51.074698 -24.163398
[73] -12.403344 -16.025922 -84.222650 -21.950431 -19.167825 -40.021951
[79] -27.117199 -17.270506 -65.171492 -48.507264 -14.898089 -15.323743
[85] -13.889967 -16.995849 -18.359679
```

So in your assignment you are assigning by indexed positions the values of `sapply`, spread out elementwise.

```
likelihoods[calc_sizes] <- sapply(calc_sizes, nb.likelihood) 

likelihoods

  [1]  -1.098612  -2.602690  -3.413620  -4.001407  -4.475865  -4.881330
  [7]  -5.240275  -5.565697  -5.865802  -6.146104  -6.410490  -6.661805
 [13]  -6.902190  -7.133302  -7.356445  -7.572668  -7.782825  -7.987619
 [19]  -8.187640  -8.383385  -8.575276  -8.763676  -8.948901  -9.131222
 [25]  -9.310881  -9.488087  -9.663029  -9.835872         NA -10.175841
 [31] -10.343221 -10.509013 -10.673316 -10.836219         NA -11.158148
 [37]         NA -11.475373 -11.632377 -11.788381 -11.943435 -12.097586
 [43]         NA -12.403344         NA -12.705964 -12.856183         NA
 [49] -13.154588         NA -13.450466         NA -13.744013 -13.889967
 [55]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
 [61] -14.898089         NA -15.182243 -15.323743         NA -15.605646
 [67]         NA -15.886160 -16.025922 -16.165367         NA         NA
 [73]         NA         NA         NA -16.995849         NA -17.270506
 [79] -17.407459         NA -17.680645         NA         NA         NA
 [85]         NA -18.359679         NA         NA         NA         NA
 [91]         NA -19.167825         NA         NA         NA -19.702968
 [97] -19.836336         NA -20.102594 -20.235490         NA -20.500835
[103]         NA         NA         NA -21.029806         NA         NA
[109] -21.425116         NA         NA         NA -21.950431         NA
[115]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[121]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[127]         NA         NA -24.034010 -24.163398 -24.292698         NA
[133]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[139]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[145]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[151]         NA         NA -27.117199         NA         NA         NA
[157]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[163]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[169]         NA -29.277798         NA         NA         NA         NA
[175]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA -30.541489
[181]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA -31.297439
[187]         NA         NA -31.674821         NA         NA         NA
[193]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[199]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[205]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[211]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[217]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[223]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[229]         NA         NA         NA         NA -37.171587         NA
[235]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[241]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[247]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[253]         NA         NA         NA -40.021951         NA         NA
[259]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[265]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[271]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[277]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[283]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[289]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[295]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[301]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[307]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[313]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[319]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[325] -48.507264         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[331]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[337]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[343]         NA         NA         NA -51.074698         NA         NA
[349]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[355]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[361]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[367]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[373]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[379]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[385]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[391]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[397]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[403]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[409]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[415]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[421]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[427]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[433]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[439]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[445]         NA         NA -63.355209         NA         NA         NA
[451]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[457]         NA         NA         NA -64.929415         NA -65.171492
[463]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[469]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[475]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[481]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[487]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[493]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[499]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[505]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[511]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[517]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[523]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[529]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[535]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[541]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[547]         NA -75.557026         NA         NA         NA         NA
[553]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[559]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[565]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[571]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[577]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[583]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[589]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[595]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[601]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[607] -82.659672         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[613]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[619]         NA -84.222650         NA         NA         NA         NA
[625]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[631]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[637]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[643]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA -87.586858
[649]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[655]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[661]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[667]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[673]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[679]         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
[685]         NA         NA         NA -92.388061
```

Notice the 70th term of `calc_size` is 688 and the 70th term of `sapply(calc_sizes, nb.likelihood)` is -92.38806 (the last numeric value above).

```
calc_sizes[70]
# [1] 688

sapply(calc_sizes, nb.likelihood)[70]
# [1] -92.3880
```

---

To resolve, run along the length of `calc_sizes` to assign by `1:87`. Also, consider initializing `likelihoods` with a length instead of growing the object after `c()`.

```
likelihoods <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(calc_sizes))

likelihoods[seq_along(calc_sizes)] <- sapply(calc_sizes, nb.likelihood) 
# likelihoods[1:length(calc_sizes)] <- sapply(calc_sizes, nb.likelihood)
```

Nevertheless, since apply family functions return an object, simple assign directly to the `sapply` call without initializing anything.

```
likelihoods <- sapply(calc_sizes, nb.likelihood) 

likelihoods
 [1]  -1.098612 -11.788381  -2.602690  -3.413620 -30.541489  -4.001407
 [7]  -8.187640  -8.575276  -6.146104 -13.154588  -4.881330  -7.987619
[13]  -4.475865  -6.410490 -17.680645  -8.948901 -31.297439 -31.674821
[19]  -5.565697 -11.943435  -9.663029  -8.383385  -5.240275  -6.661805
[25] -15.886160  -5.865802  -9.310881  -7.572668 -24.292698  -7.356445
[31] -13.450466  -9.488087  -8.763676  -7.782825 -87.586858  -9.131222
[37] -10.175841 -10.509013  -9.835872 -11.158148 -13.744013 -19.702968
[43] -12.856183  -7.133302 -75.557026 -21.425116 -11.475373 -10.343221
[49] -20.102594 -21.029806 -10.836219 -11.632377 -82.659672 -20.235490
[55] -37.171587 -12.097586 -15.605646 -24.034010 -10.673316 -29.277798
[61] -20.500835 -16.165367  -6.902190 -12.705964 -15.182243 -17.407459
[67] -19.836336 -63.355209 -64.929415 -92.388061 -51.074698 -24.163398
[73] -12.403344 -16.025922 -84.222650 -21.950431 -19.167825 -40.021951
[79] -27.117199 -17.270506 -65.171492 -48.507264 -14.898089 -15.323743
[85] -13.889967 -16.995849 -18.359679
```

<kbd>[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/IIYNLW96870)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

When you do `likelihoods[calc_sizes] <- sapply(calc_sizes, nb.likelihood)` you are saving the results of `sapply(calc_sizes, nb.likelihood)` into the vector `likelihoods` on the positions `calc_sizes`.

Since `calc_sizes` values goes from 1 to 688, R transform `likelihoods` into a 688 length vector. But if you run `table(is.na(calc_sizes))` you will see only 87 positions are not missing.

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you a simpler example to make things easier for understand, hopefully.

Assuming `v` is a vector having values from `1` to `10`, and `idx` is a subset of indices of `v`, where a function `func` will perform some replacement manipulation of `v` according to `idx`.

```
v <- 1:10
idx <- 2:6
func <- function(k) -v[k]**2
```

Till now, what is in `v` is as below:

```
> v
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Then, using `sapply(idx, func)` is to apply the function `func` over each elements in `idx`, i.e., `c(-v[2]^2,-v[3]^2,-v[4]^2,-v[5]^2,-v[6]^2)` will be output from `sapply(idx, func)`.

Finally, the output will be assigned to `v[idx]` as a replacement of original values

```
v[idx] <- sapply(idx, func)
```

Then you can see

```
> v
 [1]   1  -4  -9 -16 -25 -36   7   8   9  10
```